# How can I add an extra bind-mount to this configuration?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

There are two ways of passing arguments, I chose this one:

`sudo docker run -d  -e url=http://example.com --name myBlog -p 3001:2368 -v "$(pwd)/content":/var/lib/ghost/content ghost:latest`

How can I add an extra command line so it also adds a bind-mount to:

`$(pwd)/testFolder/config.production.json` the file on the volume would be here: `:/var/lib/ghost/config.production.json`

Also the file on the host doesn't exist yet, once I mount the container, it the container creates it.

This is what I've tried:

`sudo docker run -d  -e url=http://example.com --name myBlog6 -p 3006:2376 -v "$(pwd)/content6":/var/lib/ghost/content -v /home/ubuntu/config6:/var/lib/ghost/config.production.json ghost:latest`

But I'm getting this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/home/ubuntu/config6\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f8c4ed9231552e91caaeb4f0b8fb9f02108f838e94b659bf049a2df365cd26ef/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f8c4ed9231552e91caaeb4f0b8fb9f02108f838e94b659bf049a2df365cd26ef/merged/var/lib/ghost/config.production.json\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it correctly, you get this error because you are trying to mount directory `/home/ubuntu/config6` to a file `...config.production.json`.

If you say that file `config.production.json` will be created and it's content is written in run time after the container is initialized, then you could try to created an empty file

```
touch /home/ubuntu/config6/config.production.json
sudo chmod 777 /home/ubuntu/config6/config.production.json
```

and then mount a file to the container

```
sudo docker run -d \
  -e url=http://example.com \
  --name myBlog6 -p 3006:2376 \
  -v "$(pwd)/content6":/var/lib/ghost/content \
  -v /home/ubuntu/config6/config.production.json:/var/lib/ghost/config.production.json \
  ghost:latest
```

And after container will write a content to file, you will be able to see it and load next time to the container.

The `chmod` command is used to make sure, that you app running inside of the container will have rights to write to this file.

Comment: I tried that `sudo docker run -d -e url=http://example.com --name myBlog -p 3001:2368 -v "$(pwd)/content":/var/lib/ghost/content -v /var/www/myBlog/config.production.json:/var/lib/ghost/config.production.json ghost:latest` and it's giving me the same error. It thinks I'm binding a folder with a file